# Makefile: If $^ gets all the prerequisites, what could be used to get all the targets

Tags: makefile, gnu, targets

This is the idea:

```
$(filenameParam)_%.sfx : commun_prereq.per
     mycommand $< (all my $@)
```

where % can be any one letter, some times e,f some times e,s, some times h,r,t, basically any file with a letter in there.

Comment: Pattern rules instantiate as many rules as there are matching targets. So your rule is not just one, it's as many as there are `*.sfx` files when you invoke make. And for each of them, `$@` matches the specific target. What you want is not clear. What do you expect from make when none of the `*.sfx` exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given invocation of a rule there is only ever one target and the name of that target is put into the `$@` automatic variable.  When make is trying to build a target `foo_h.sfx` then `$@` will be `foo_h.sfx`; when make is trying to build a target `foo_r.sfx` then `$@` will be `foo_r.sfx`, etc.

There is one additional wrinkle: it's possible to have multiple target patterns in a pattern rule.  That causes make to build all those targets in a single invocation of the rule.  In this case, `$@` is the target that make wanted to build that caused this rule to be fired.  If you want to get one of the other targets you need to construct it yourself using `$*` which matches the pattern.  So:

```
%.x %.y :
        @echo '@ = $@ / * = $*'
```

will get the output:

```
$ make foo.x
@ = foo.x / * = foo

$ make foo.y
@ = foo.y / * = foo
```